# Training Keras autoencoder without bottleneck does not return original data

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to make an autoencoder using Keras with a tensorflow backend. In particular, I have data of a vector of n_components (i.e. 200) sampled n_times (i.e. 20000). It is key that when I train time t, that I compare it only to time t. It appears that it is shuffling the sampling times. I removed the bottleneck and find that the network is doing a pretty bad job of predicting the n_components, instead representing something more like the mean of the input scaled by each component.

Here is my network with the bottleneck commented out:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

# Make a 7-layer autoencoder network
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_components, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_components,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_components, activation='relu'))
# model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
# model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'))
# model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_components, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_components, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# act is a numpy matrix of size (n_components, n_times)
model.fit(act.T, act.T, epochs=15, batch_size=100, shuffle=False) 
newact = model.predict(act.T).T
```

I have tested shuffling the second component of act, n_times, and passing it as model.fit(act.T, act_shuffled.T) and see no difference from model.fit(act.T, act.T). Am I doing something wrong? How can I force it to learn from the specific time?

Many thanks,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have solved the problem, but more knowledgeable users of Keras might be able to correct me. I had tried many different values for the argument batch_size of fit, but I didn't try a value of 1. When I changed it to 1, it did a good job of reproducing the input data.

I believe that the batch size, even if shuffle is set to False, allows the autoencoder to train one input time against an unrelated input time.

So, I have ammended my code to:

```
model.fit(act.T, act.T, epochs=15, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```